# cannot use optional chaining on non-optional value of type 'Any' SWIFT

Tags: ios, json, swift

I'm extremely new to Swift and I'm having trouble building a weather app that utilizes the API from a website called openweathermap.org. When the user enter a city and clicks "SUBMIT" they should be able to see a label that displays the description of the weather.

The results in JSON are:

```
(
        {
        description = haze;
        icon = 50d;
        id = 721;
        main = Haze;
    },
        {
        description = mist;
        icon = 50d;
        id = 701;
        main = Mist;
    }
)
```

While attempting to debug, I used the code: print(jsonResult["weather"]!) and this allows me to see the above JSON details. However, I can't seem to get it to work when I try to get the description of the weather.

My goal: I am trying to get the description of the weather to display on my app. I am currently getting the error: cannot use optional chaining on non-optional value of type 'Any'. Your help would be most appreciated!

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var cityTextField: UITextField!

    @IBOutlet weak var resultLabel: UILabel!


    @IBAction func submit(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        // getting a url
        if let url = URL(string: "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=" + (cityTextField.text?.replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "%20"))! + ",uk&appid=08b5523cb95dde0e2f68845a635f14db") {

        // creating a task from the url to get the content of that url
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
            if error != nil {
                print("error")
            } else {
                print("no error")
                if let urlContent = data {
                    do {
                        let jsonResult = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: urlContent, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as! [String:Any]
                        //print(jsonResult["weather"]!)
                        if let description = jsonResult["weather"]??[0]["description"] as? String {
                            DispatchQueue.main.sync(execute:{
                                self.resultLabel.text = description
                            })
                        }
                    } catch {
                        print("JSON processing failed")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        task.resume()
        } else {
            resultLabel.text = "Couldn't find weather for that city. Please try a different city."
        }
    }
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
    }
```

Comment: You have two question marks here (after weather): `jsonResult["weather"]??[0]["description"]` try removing one of them for a start and see if that gets you any further

Comment: This article is worth reading: https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=37 (I know that you probably has got enough reading to do already but this article gives - I think - a good introduction to parsing JSON in Swift with an optional initializer for instance)

Comment: @pbodsk Thanks for the tip!

Comment: @pbodsk I will definitely give that article a read. Thank you! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
let jsonResult = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: urlContent, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as! [String:Any]


    let weather = jsonResult["weather"] as! [[String : Any]]
    if let description = weather[0]["description"] as? String {

        print(description)
    }
```

Comment: what is myjson variable  in your answer refers?

Comment: hoops.. sorry it's jsonResult

Comment: @Rob Thank you so much!!! That worked like a charm. I really appreciate your helpful answer...it made my day. :-D

Comment: @AdrianaGiancarlaPope Welcome ;)

Answer (score 0):

You've confused the compiler here by using "??"

```
if let description = jsonResult["weather"]??[0]
```

The proper syntax is just to use one "?"

```
if let description = jsonResult["weather"]?[0]
```

But then you'll get another error because in the line:

```
let jsonResult = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: urlContent, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as! [String:Any]
```

You said that `jsonResult["weather"` will give you type `Any`.  Not type Array.

So you need to unwrap as an array like:

```
if let descriptions = jsonResult["weather"] as? [[String : Any]], let description = descriptions[0]
```

And so on.

Comment: Thank you for your help! :-)